# Is it possible to specify a weight and a minimum height?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to have an element that has a height of at least 160 dp, but scales to use all of the space available when possible. I think that perhaps this is more difficult than what I expected.

The following does not work, but maybe it conveys the idea of what I want to do.

```kotlin
Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()).fillMaxSize) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f).sizeIn(minHeight = 160.dp))
    Box(modifier = Modifier.height(600.dp))
}
```

When the content doesn't fit the screen, I want the content to be scrollable, and the first box to be 160 dp in height. If the screen is more than 760 dp, I want first box to fill as much space as possible without causing the need to scroll.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [**`BoxWithConstraints`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#boxwithconstraints) to define its own content according to the available space.
Something like:

```
BoxWithConstraints {
    val height = maxHeight
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState(0))
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        val modifierBox1 : Modifier = if (height > 760.dp)
            Modifier.heightIn(height - 600.dp)
        else
            Modifier.heightIn(160.dp)

        Box(
            modifier = modifierBox1
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Blue)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(600.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Green)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering my question again. This is pretty much perfect. The only problem it has is that you need to be able to calculate the size of box 2 independently. In real usage it's pretty simple and static. If the height of box 2 were dynamic (based on its own content, not based on layout constraints), would there be a way to measure that or we you need to use a custom layout? Regardless, this works well for my usage. Thank you!

Comment: @Sean I don't think there is a general answer that can cover all the scenarios.The `BoxWithConstraints` is a `SubcomposeLayout` and I think that for more complex cases the way is a custom `Layout` or a `SubcomposeLayout`.